# Events are not rendered when retrieving them from Google Calendar JSON encoded

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm using CodeIgniter to build an application with a Fullcalendar and I'm trying to integrate Google calendar.

I had trouble using the JS and preferred to use PHP, so I have a controller called `Calendar.php` to call the Google Calendar API, get the primary calendar and list the events.

*Edit*: This is what I'm getting now:

[image]

The object looks like this

GET http://localhost/admin/calendar/gcal...?start=2016-09-25&end=2016-11-06&_=1476324367596

200 OK 2.68s

Response

[{"title":"lobna elatreby @nrc","type":"gcal","calendar_id":356,"notes":"notes","start":"2010-03-23T14
:30:00-04:00","end":"2010-03-23T15:30:00-04:00"},{"title":"Biology Test 1","type":"gcal","calendar_id"
:356,"notes":"notes","start":"2013-02-08T18:30:00-05:00","end":"2013-02-08T19:30:00-05:00"}]

I used json_encode(['events'=>$eventsArr]) and I got the same error

Deprecation warning: moment().zone is deprecated, use moment().utcOffset instead. 
Arguments: 2010-03-23T14:30:00-04:00

deprecate/fullcalendar/moment.min.js:309:98...............

**TypeError: t.start is undefined**

function C(t){null==t.allDay&&(t.allDay=!(t.start.hasTime()||t.end&&t.end.hasTime...

I tried download & updated Moment.js, I tried changing the date format ... Google Calender API **"The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone."**

Comment: Just copy the request response and verify if the string is a valid JSON using (JSON formatter){https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/] (for example). If the json isn't valid, the events won't be rendered. To reply to this message be sure to add @milz on the comment.

Comment: @milz you are absolutely right, I'm trying to fix the date format but codeigniter date helper will not format it to RFC-4627. It will format to ISO-8601, HTTP Cookies, Atom and a few RFC formats that I used the jsonformatter with and apparently don't work. Is there a way to convert the date using standard php? thank you

Comment: Please copy the json string and post it on your question instead of the image. I cannot test it without the full json string. Thanks.

Comment: I am still having problems with the date ... I updated my post and edited and added the object. @milz

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/grwsppvm/). I've taken the events and everything is working as expected. You should note, however, that you have a space between **14** and **:30** on "start":"2010-03-23T14 :30:00-04:00". You should also note what is the version you're using for momentjs and fullcalendar

Comment: So it is the object not the timezone. I got it to render after using your code for the object and using strtotime to change the date format  .. thanks. you were a lot of help. I appreciate you taking the time to make the fiddle and I looked at different ones on your profile. will follow you @milz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are returning from the server is not a valid JSON and the issue doesn't have to do with the date. Just take a look at the screenshot you've posted, that has something like:

> {"events": {"description":"lobna elatreby @nrc", "start": "2010-03-23T14:30:00-04:00", "end": "2010-03-23T15:30:00-04:00"}}{"events":...

You're setting the multiple `events` and this is because of the code on the `gcalendar_events` function. You need to update the code to (take a look at the end of the method:

```
function gcalendar_events() {
    $client = $this->getClient();

    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    // $client->setRedirectUri(site_url('calendar/gcalendar'));
    //$client->setAccessType('offline'); need calendar events to appear even if not logged in to google
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $id = 'primary';   
        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
        $calendar = $service->calendars->get('primary');

        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();

        $events = $service->events->listEvents($id);

        $eventsArr = [];

        foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {          
            // Append a new evet to the $eventsArr
            $eventsArr[] = array()
                'description' => $event->getSummary(),               
                'start'=> $event->getStart()->dateTime,                   
                'end' =>  $event->getEnd()->dateTime,
            ); 
        }  

        // Return a single `events` with all the `$eventsArr`
        echo json_encode(['events' => $eventsArr]);
    }
}
```

This should return something like:

> {"events": [{"description":"lobna elatreby @nrc", "start": "2010-03-23T14:30:00-04:00", "end": "2010-03-23T15:30:00-04:00"}, {"description": "...", "start": ...}]

Comment: I looked at the DOM window object constructor in the firebug debugger and the dateformatter is red ... does that mean there is an error in the date again? I don't know what to do about the date .. my ical and other calendars are showing this format Y-m-d H:i:s @milz

Comment: @dr_neevmorgan I don't think the issue has something to do with the date because momentjs can deal with many different formats. Also, firebug could be telling the error is somewhere but the issue is on another place. What I suggest is that you update the method as I've described on the answer and, if it still doesn't work, copy the entire string from the response (the json object) and edit your question with that string. This is the only way I can pinpoint the issue. Thanks!

Comment: It is the date and moment.js can't format it.. will you take a look at the error it is dropping now ..